# Chart js - Line chart getting cut from top and right

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I was trying to plot a line graph using chart js. The graph is getting cut from right and top. Tried using padding but still facing the same issue. Another issue is the x and y axis lines are very light. They are rarely visible.
Here is the graph that is getting cut [https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz9a2.jpg].

This is the code that is have tried

```js
var time = ["0", "150", "0", "10", "20", "30", "0", "150", "0", "150", "0", "150", "0", "50", "200", "250", "200", "300"]
var temperature = ["50", "650", "50", "650", "850", "1030", "50", "560", "50", "560", "50", "560", "50", "1200", "1250", "1300", "1350", "1400"]
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    ctx.width=500;
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
         data: {
            labels: time,
            datasets: [{
                borderColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
                data: temperature,
                fill:false,
                steppedLine: true,
            }]
        },
         options: {
                bezierCurve : false,
                animation: false,
                    legend: false,
                    //Changing Plugins
                    plugins:{
                    datalabels: {
                    color: '#1a1b1c',
                    align: 'end',
                    anchor: 'end',
                    font: {
                    weight: 'bold',
                    size: 20,
            },
            },
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                                display: true,
                                fontColor: 'black',
                                fontSize:20,
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: 'Time',
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    fontColor: "black",
                                    fontStyle: "bold",
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                  },
                                  gridLines: {
                                    display:false
                                }
                            }],
                        yAxes: [{
                                display: true,
                                fontColor: 'black',
                                fontSize:20,
                                scaleLabel:{
                                    labelString: 'Temperature',
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: false,
                                    steps: 100,
                                    stepValue: 25,
                                    //max: 1200,
                                    fontColor: "black", 
                                    fontStyle: "bold",
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                },
                                gridLines: {
                                    display:false
                                },
                            }],
                    },
    },
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: In the sample it looks fine, which means it's likely a styling issue. Can you share your html and css?

Comment: You can change the colour of the axes, for example: `gridLines: {
                                    display:false,
                                    color: 'red'
                                },`

Comment: Well I was trying to print it on a paper so showing all the html and css related stuff. `<td colspan="12">
    <div class="chart-container" style="width: 22cm;margin-top:10px">
   <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </td>`. Css `canvas#myChart
{
 height: 60% !important;
 width: 100% !important;
}`